# Android Webview - Click event doesnt fires

Tags: android, jquery, events, webview, click

I got a Android application where i have a Webview in.
The webview loada webbpage of mine, where i do alot of jQuery
events in.

My problem is, that some of the elements that i have click events on, is not working.
But if i click on one of those elements that is not working, alot of times in a row, 
then the click event fires away.

Before the html elements was div's, now i have changed them to a's. But still the same results.

Is there something i need to change in the Android application to get this working?

Here is some settings that i've done for the Android Webview:

`WebSettings settings = w.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true); 
        settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH); 
        settings.setSupportZoom(false); 
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true); 
        settings.setSavePassword(false); 
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false); 
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);`

a typical click event is like

`$('#Element').click(function() { ... });`

NOTICE:
Ive tried to run the website on a normal browser in the mobile,
in the android's own browser its like in the application.
in Android mobile Chrome it works like a charm!

Is there a way to launch Mobile Chrome inside the webview instead of the one that just is loaded..

Or is there another way to handle this damn bugg?

Comment: Is JavascriptInterface an option?

Comment: I've got one of those. To fire some online and offline stuff from the Android app to the website. But i was hoping that I missed something when it comes to a newer OS of Android and thier click events. Because on a old Android OS like 2.3. The application works great with its click events.

Comment: I have same problem :/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142441/maps-v3-onclick-android-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Put the context, for example

```
$('a#Element').click(function() { ... });
```

it solved my problem