# Maps v3 onclick Android not work

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Can someone tell me why this does not work on android?

**Works fine** in iPhone(Safari) OSX(safari,chrome), **but** in Android (webView) not handler click :/

```
// lot of code
$(".btnCenter").on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    map.setZoom(19);  
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());  
});  

$(".btnAll").on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());  
    bounds.extend(start);  
    bounds.extend(end);  
    mapd.fitBounds(bounds);  
});
```

Thank's

Comment: You need to specify which version of Android (not all WebViews are created equal) and link to a full reproducible case. JSFiddle works if your code isn't publicly accessible. In particular, I would want to see the context for `.btnCenter`.

Comment: you're right, put the context and work fine :) thanks